# TextBox Highlighting not happening in Desktop C# application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In Desktop C# Form or window I have a search box which is TextBox, when user try to highlight the text Using Ctrl + A, The system release sound. Is there any thing that make the textbox control accept Ctrl + A?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop the Bell on CTRL-A (WinForms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225711/stop-the-bell-on-ctrl-a-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do try this:

```
       private void textBox1_keyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                textBox1.SelectAll();
        }
```

Comment: Yepp, only valid in Multi-line mode though, otherwise Ctrl+A works out of the box.